# How to programmatically draw a etched line to use as separators in plain tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, separator

The `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched` is only available in grouped table view. I want to produce the same effect on a plain table view, so I am thinking of drawing it programmatically.  Is it feasible? If yes, how to do I do that?

Comment: plz provide a screenshot exactly wt u need..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a screenshot and zoom in. It looks like two parallel horizontal lines, one white and one grey. That will be simple enough to draw yourself, probably during a custom drawRect in your cell subclass.